# Sharing Authentication a Sharepoint Portal and MVC Web Application

Tags: forms-authentication

I have a Sharepoint 2010 portal where users can access a variety of apps, I am attempting to have the portal be a single-sign on using forms authentication for all the apps. Currently users sign into the portal, then when they open one of the apps they have to enter the same credentials again to sign into the individual apps. I did some reading on this and read that if I put this into my web.config (both portal and app) the credentials should be shared:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/auth/login"
             timeout="720"
             name=".MYCOOKIE"
             domain=".mydomain.ca"
             protection="All"
             path="/"
             requireSSL="false"
             enableCrossAppRedirects="true"/>

<machineKey validationKey="myvalkey" decryptionKey="mydeckey" validation="SHA1" />
```

My understanding is the credentials would be stored in `.MYCOOKIE` when a user logs into the portal, then opens one of the apps the cookie should provide the authentication data to the app and the user would automatically get signed in. It doesn't work, users still have to sign in...am I missing something?? It appears the issue is on the sharepoint portal end, when I check `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is returns false. These are SSL sites, not sure if that changes anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would there be a problem if my default page doesn't require the user to be logged in?  The site has some features that unauthorized users can see and an additional set of features based on user's credentials.  Just wondering...still trying to figure out why this isn't working...

Comment: would the values in my membership and roleManager attributes be playing any role in this?

Comment: In my MVC app when I look in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies there is only the _RequestVerificationToken cookie, no ".MYCOOKIE" so I guess it is on the sharepoint end.  Do I have to create a cookie manually??  Please please any help would be greatly appreciated.